# Filter cleared when changing month

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have the following code, which filters FullCalendar by dates, content of items etc.The problem I have, is the filter is not respected when the month is changed. Seems like the calendar internally caches the initial source.

Can anyone help?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: getUrl()
     });

    $('#siteSelect').click(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', '');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', getUrl());


    });

    function getUrl() {
       return 'api/Event?' + getFilter();
    } 

    $("#toggleButton").click(function () {
        $("#toggleDiv").slideToggle("slow");

    });

});

function getFilter() {
    return $("#filterForm").serialize();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a function for this instead

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: getUrl(),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                callback(JSON.parse(data));
            }
        });
    }
    ...
});
```